# Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker' after ADT update

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-analytics, classnotfoundexception

I've updated the ADT to v23.0.5, and on a previously working project the Google Analytics is not working.
The exact error on the logcat is:

```
 VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker;)
 Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker', referenced from method com.mypackage.myApp.getTracker
 VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 587 (Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker;) in Lcom/myApp/MyApplication;
```

Previously, I also use Google Analytics v4. I check a bunch of Answers, like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25360884/google-analytics-v4-in-android-could-not-find-class-com-google-android-gms-ana), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125774/gms-analytics-googleanalytics-noclassdeffounderror),  [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076446/android-could-not-find-method-com-google-analytics-tracking-android-easytracke)

Summarize, that I do/check:

- I use Eclipse, and cannot migrate to Android studio because of some eclipse plugin I use.
- my project and the google-play-services_lib is imported by Import/'Existing Android code into workspace', and 'Copy prijects into workspace' is also checked
- The library project is added
- I also check the `project.properties`, The relevant file content seems to be OK: `android.library.reference.1=../google-play-services_lib`, I cannot turn on the proguard
- no compile error
- on project properties, the Java Build Path/Order and Export: both Android Private Libraries and Android Dependencies are checked
- after clean, my project `bin/dexedLibs` contains the following files:

  - `android-support-v4-*`
  - `androidplot-core-0.6.1-*` (comes from a project/libs)
  - `google-play-services_lib-*`
  - `google-play-services-*`
  - `gson-2.2.4-*` (comes from a project/libs)

Do anyone have any idea, what I miss? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I reinstall the whole ADT (what a shame), and finally it gets working. The only difference is in my .classpath file (order of entries):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
-    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
-    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
     <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
     <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
     <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
     <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
 +   <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
 +   <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```